# Azure Databricks can Autoloader use AD credential passthrough?

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-autoloader

I am unable to authenticate to ADLS Gen2 when using Autoloader. My Databricks cluster is enabled with my AD credentials. This pass-through allows the following read and write from ADLS Gen2.

```
filepath_read = "abfss://container@storage_account.dfs.core.windows.net/output/parquet_file.pq"
filepath_write = "abfss://container@storage_account.dfs.core.windows.net/output/data_write/"
df = spark.read.parquet(filepath)
display(df)
df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(filepath_write)
```

I assumed this access would allow me to create a stream, if useNotifications was set to false. However when trying to create a streaming query with autoloader it fails. I find this odd, because I assume I only need read and write access since I am not setting up additional services with useNotifications set to false. I initialized the stream with:

```
cloud_file = {"cloudFiles.format":"parquet",
              "cloudFiles.useNotifications":"false",
              "cloudFiles.subscripionId":subscripionId,
              "cloudFiles.connectionString":connection_string,
              "cloudFiles.tenantId":tenantId,
              "cloudFiles.resourceGroup":resourceGroup
              
              }
df_read_stream =(spark
     .readStream
     .format("cloudFiles")
     .options(**cloud_file)
     .schema(schema)
     .load("abfss://container@storage_account.dfs.core.windows.net/raw_landing"))
```

Then attempted to write the stream with:

```
df_read_stream.writeStream \
    .format("delta") \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .foreachBatch(flatten) \
    .trigger(once = True) \
    .option("checkpointLocation",checkpoint_location) \
    .start("abfss://container@storage_account.dfs.core.windows.net/transformed/transformed_delta_table")
```

Execution returns this error:

```
com.databricks.backend.daemon.data.client.adl.AzureCredentialNotFoundException: Could not find ADLS Gen2 Token
```

Do I need additional credentials to authenticate even with AD credential pass-through enabled?

Answer (score 1):

The above ***error*** mainly happens because the ***ADLS Gen2*** is properly ***not*** ***connected*** to ***azure Databricks***

Please follow below **syntax** for connecting **ADLS Gen2** to **ADB** and make sure to copy the **storage account key**.

[image: Ref1]

> **Connecting ADLS Gen2 to Azure Databricks**

```
spark.conf.set(
"fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.core.windows.net","<storage-account-Access key>")
```

**Or**

If you are **trying** to **mount**, follow this code:

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
source = "wasbs://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/",
mount_point = "/mnt/azo1",
extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net":"<storage-account-Access key>"})
```

[image: Ref2]

For **info**, refer to this official [***Microsoft document***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/credential-passthrough/adls-passthrough),

Configuring **Auto Loader** in Azure Databricks follow this [**link**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNG-5uRY4o8), it has a detailed explanation about read and write ***streaming data*** on the ***Azure Databricks***.

Comment: Thank you  @BhanunagasaiVamsi-MT. That indeed solved the problem, if I create a new cluster not enabled with credential pass through and add that token. However I am wondering why AD credentials are not being passed through to autoloader? I would think that token would be passed through since I am able to read and write to ADLS Gen2.